# Arguments with spaces are not passing to Python Script

Tags: python, xml, arguments, parameter-passing, token

I have the below line in XML file where am calling the calling the Pythonscript and passing the arguements.

| mypythonscript modifiedby="$env:user_realname$"

$env:user_realname$ is a environment token which pulls the value of current user who is accessing the XML file.

the token passed above to modifiedby can contain names with spaces like

Ex1: Peter

Ex2: Peter Parker

Its working & passing the name with single word, but not working in names with more than single valued( Working but passing only the first word).

I tried to put the qoutes around token(argument), no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Quotes around the argument is the correct way, can you show your code?

Comment: When you say "I have the below line which am calling in XML file," what do you mean by that? How do you call a line in an XML file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is the line in my python file --- modifiedby = argvals.get("modifiedby"), when i print modifiedby variable i only get the first value of the name, even if the name has first name & last name

Comment: Could you post the entire source, or at a minimum a [Minimum Verifiable Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Doing so will allow readers here to exactly duplicate the issue you're having, making it much easier for it to be solved.